# displaying a image from a database using PHP

Tags: php, apache

I have two servers. Both are using Apache/2.4.25 and PHP 5.6

I have a page that renders an image retrieved from the DB

in the page i have the snippet

```
<img alt="" class="tiff" data-itype="<?= $iTypeID ?>"
     src="../utils/archive_grab.php?id=<?=urlEncrypt($imageId)?>&xval=<?=urlEncrypt("blob")?>" width="550" />
```

archive_grab.php does

```
$query = "SELECT image FROM myimages where id=?";
$result = xquery_ccon($query,array($id));
$data=array_pop($result);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $data['image'];
```

this only works fine on Server1 but not on Server2. Server1 displays as expected and Server2 displays a broken image.

While debugging, I put this in-line on Server2 that was displaying the broken links and it displayed the image correctly

```
<?
    $query = "SELECT image FROM myimages where id=131078";
    $result = xquery_ccon($query,array($id));
    $data=array_pop($result);
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $data['image'] ).'"/>';
?>
```

but i can not put it in-line permanently, because i call archive_grab.php from lots of other places.

So the three variables are

1. apache and its setttings (since the versions are the same)
2. php and its settings
3. mysql

can anyone think of something that would cause this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: i would check the headers in a browser between the two

Comment: Hello smith, thanks for the response. Looking at the request and response headers they are the same. And looking at the size downloaded they are the same as well

Comment: last guess try adding `header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="cat.jpg"');` with the other header of course. caching, output buffering, same on both servers?

Comment: Pointing at the same database server and tables and such?  Or if different server then at least same version and table structure etc? All same versions of PHP and various extensions/mods/etc?

Comment: ivanivan , yes same code, both db and php(different servers). that is why i think it must be some kind of apache or php config setting

Answer (score 0):

I've once got this kind of errors when one php file was saved as UTF-8 **WITHOUT** BOM and the other **WITH** BOM. The additional BOM in one file spoiled the output.